# interface generic hierarchy

Tags: c#, generic-interface

I have some generic interface linked one to each other.

```
public interface IA
{
    int val { get; set; }
}
public interface IB<T> where T:IA
{
    T a_val { get; set; }
}
public interface IC<T> where T : IB<IA>
{
    T b_val { get; set; }
}

public class a:IA
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}
public class b:IB<a>
{
    public a a_val { get; set; }
}
public class c:IC<b>
{
    public b b_val { get; set; }
}
```

For the last class c, i have an error:

> The type 'b' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   or method 'IC'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'b'
>   to 'IB'.

How can I properly use generic interfaces in this case ?

Answer (score 7):

`T` in `IC<T>` is required to be an `IB<IA>`. You have given it an `IB<A>`.  You have no guarantee that an `IB<A>` can be used as an `IB<IA>` just because `A` implements `IA`.

Think about it this way: if `IB<T>` means "I can eat anything of type T", and `IA` means "I am a fruit", and `A` means "apple", then `IB<IA>` means "I can eat any fruit", and `IB<A>` means "I can eat any apple". If some code wants to feed you bananas and grapes then it needs to take an `IB<IA>`, not an `IB<A>`.

Let's suppose `IB<A>` could be converted to `IB<IA>` and see what goes wrong:

```
class AppleEater : IB<Apple> 
{  
    public Apple a_val { get; set; }
}
class Apple : IA 
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}
class Orange : IA 
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}
...
IB<Apple> iba = new AppleEater();
IB<IA> ibia = iba; // Suppose this were legal. 
ibia.a_val = new Orange(); // ibia.a_val is of type IA and Orange implements IA
```

And now we just set `iba.val`, which is a property of type `Apple` to a reference to an object of type `Orange`.

That's why the conversion has to be illegal.

So how can you make this legal?

As the code stands, you cannot, because as I've just shown, it isn't typesafe.

You can make it legal by marking `T` as `out` like this: `interface IB<out T>`.  However, it is then illegal to use `T` in any "input context". In particular, you cannot have any property of type `T` that has a setter.  If we make that restriction then the problem disappears because `a_val` cannot be set to an instance of `Orange` *because it is read-only*.

This question is asked extremely frequently on SO. Look for questions about "covariance and contravariance" in C# for plenty of examples.

Comment: To quote Monty Python: "My Brain Hurts!"

Comment: @RBarryYoung: you'll want to read this then: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/24/5529183.aspx (Note that this series was written *before* covariance and contravariance was added to C# 4.0, so I'm using the notation `<-T>` to mean `<in T>`. We had not decided on a syntax yet when I wrote the series.)

Comment: Ouch!  I sure wouldn't want to be the entry-level programmer assigned to maintain this kind of thing.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it can be done easier (and a bit more *clean*), but this code compiles:

```
public interface IA
{
    int val { get; set; }
}
public interface IB<T> where T : IA
{
    T a_val { get; set; }
}
public interface IC<T, U> where T : IB<U> where U : IA
{
    T b_val { get; set; }
}

public class a : IA
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}
public class b : IB<a>
{
    public a a_val { get; set; }
}
public class c : IC<b, a>
{
    public b b_val { get; set; }
}
```

What's even more important, it don't let you do something like that:

```
public class a1 : IA
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}

public class c : IC<b, a1>
{
    public b b_val { get; set; }
}
```

Compiler throws following error:

> The type 'ConsoleApplication2.b' cannot be used as type parameter 'T'
>   in the generic type or method 'ConsoleApplication2.IC'. There is
>   no implicit reference conversion from 'ConsoleApplication2.b' to
>   'ConsoleApplication2.IB'.

And that is really cool feature, isn't it?

Comment: +1 for digging into that one, with generics you do in fact have to chain the specificity.